# Distribution over the product of three, or $n$, independent Beta random variables

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution, approximation, moment-generating-function

This is a re-post of a question on the Mathematica stack exchange, as per the advice of another user (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/distribution-over-the-product-of-three-or-n-independent-beta-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment248198_91407)). I am pursuing a computational solution there, but thought it might be worth looking for a pen-and-paper method.

I would like to calculate the PDF for the product of three independent Beta random variables. Specifically, I would like to find the distribution of the product of the following: $X_1\sim \textrm{Beta}(1,3/2)$, $X_2\sim \textrm{Beta}(3/2,1)$ and $X_3\sim \textrm{Beta}(2,1/2)$.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? The reason I state $n$ in the question is because I would like eventually to generalise this calculation to the product of more $\textrm{Beta}$ random variables.

Answer (score 1):

I read this as about the distribution of the product of independent beta distributed random variables. A good tool to study the (distribution of) product of independent random variables is the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#In_probability_theory). The Mellin transform of a beta random variable can be calculated as (an elementary integral)
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   M_X(s) = \E X^s = \frac{B(\alpha+s,\beta)}{B(\alpha,\beta)}
$$
where $B( , )$ is the Beta function. The Mellin transform of the (independent) product $X_1 \dotsm X_n$ is the the product of the Mellin transforms $M_{X_i}(s)$.

If that cannot be inverted exactly, the saddlepoint approximation for instance can be used to find a very good approximation for the density. (I will post here some examples, later). [This paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2099424.pdf) finds some general expressions using the Mellin transform approach above, but general solutions do not have a simple form. So the approximation route above could be more practical.